# /swagger-ui/index.html not found

Tags: nginx, jhipster

I follow here to setup separated front-end and back-end in centos 7 (with docker), using nginx to host my front-end, my website works, and all /api/.... requests work, however, when I want to check RESTful API serviced by swagger, got a 404 error, fiddler says:

```
not found /swagger-ui/index.html
```

I open 8080 on host and navigate the swagger-ui folder and index.html is just there. and all www folder is given 755 permission.

The nginx site.conf is as below:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    index index.html;
    server_name localhost;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    location / {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }
    location /api {
        proxy_pass http://www.example.com:8080/api;
    }
    location /management {
        proxy_pass http://www.example.com:8080/management;
    }
    location /v2 {
       proxy_pass http://www.example.com:8080/v2;
    }
    location /swagger-ui {
        proxy_pass http://www.example.com:8080/swagger-ui;
    }
    location /swagger-resources {
        proxy_pass http://www.example.com:8080/swagger-resources;
    }
}
```

What's wrong?

===============================updated
after issue:

```
sudo docker logs -f -t --tail 100 docker_nginx_1
```

found somethings wrong in log file:

```
2018-07-14T17:35:40.904857522Z 187.67.50.246 - - [14/Jul/2018:17:35:40 +0000] "GET /cgi/common.cgi HTTP/1.1" 404 169 "-" "Wget(linux)" "-"
2018-07-14T17:35:40.904920067Z 2018/07/14 17:35:40 [error] 5#5: *23 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/cgi/common.cgi" failed (2: No such file or directory), client:187.67.50.246, server: localhost, request: "GET /cgi/common.cgi HTTP/1.1", host: "39.107.246.223"
2018-07-14T17:35:43.896984659Z 187.67.50.246 - - [14/Jul/2018:17:35:43 +0000] "GET /stssys.htm HTTP/1.1" 404 169 "-" "Wget(linux)" "-"
```

Comment: just cannot find error.log file in /var/log/nginx folder, in /var/lib/docker/<contain id>, found a xxx-json.log, it says: {"log":"221.217.121.209 - - [14/Jul/2018:12:42:58 +0000] \"GET /swagger-ui/index.html HTTP/1.1\" 404 1302 \"http://www.sample.com/\" \"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/67.0.3396.99 Safari/537.36\" \"-\"\n","stream":"stdout","time":"2018-07-14T12:42:58.177129055Z"}

Comment: Does not look like you have enabled debug mode. Have you tried commenting out all other locations and keeping only /swagger-ui and /swagger-resources? You could also try adding a trailing `/`

Comment: suspect it is nginx config related issue, after docker-compose up, the folders /var/log/nginx and /usr/share/nginx do not existing, and I create such two folders, can't nginx docker automatically create such folders? or something else I missed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works after I comment out:

```
location /swagger-ui {
    proxy_pass http://www.example.com:8080/swagger-ui;
}
```

I thought swagger-ui was served by nginx instead of back-end.